# Xcode5 - toggle button border color automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I new to IOS programming.
I want to toggle button border color automatically at start of apps to get user attention,
I have tried the below code, but only the final color is selected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    button.layer.borderWidth=2.5f;
    button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:3.0];
    button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:6.0];
    button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: So what you want is an animation of 3 border colours in your button?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is an invalid way to chain animations. As a result, only the last changes are applied. Additionally, you should be using block based animations, which Apple has recommended since iOS 4. Should be something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    button.layer.borderWidth=2.5f;
    button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
    }  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Correct, but boy is this ugly as sin when you have to chain blocks like this--I'd declare block variables myself.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is the same as *0x7fffffff*'s answer, except it uses block variables so it looks a little cleaner and hopefully makes more sense:

```
void (^animateToRed)(BOOL finished) = ^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    } completion: nil];
}

void (^animateToClear)(BOOL finished) = ^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
    }  completion:animateToRed];
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    button.layer.borderWidth=2.5f;
    button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
} completion:animateToClear];
```

`UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method is the best way to animate changes over time.

It takes 3 arguments.

- A duration as a CGFloat, which is a measure of the length of the animation in seconds.
- An animation block, which tells what animations to perform.
- A completion block, which allows you to execute code after the animation is complete.

This code snippet creates two completion blocks.

The `animateToRed` completion block handles the animating of the border to red.  It's completion block is `nil`, at this point, we're done animating.

The `animateToClear` completion block handles the animating of the border to clear.  It's completion block is the `animateToRed` which we just defined.

Finally, we call `animateWithDuration`, animating the border to blue, and passing the `animateToClear` block for the completion (which in turn calls the `animateToRed` block).

For an animation this simple and with no repeated animations, it may seem like slightly overkill to do it this way (though it is slightly more readable).  However, with a more complicated series of animations, especially if there's any repetitiveness, creating block variables like this to use and pass quickly becomes quite helpful.